Power two microcontrollers with different voltages from one power supply
Background: We want to extend a Lasertag blaster with a Raspberry Pi Pico microcontroller (and more peripherals, e.g. LEDs, IR TX & RX, buttons).
Goal: Use the existing 4xAA battery source (6-7V). However, the Pico accepts 1.8 - 5.5V. So we want to slightly lower the provided voltage.
Solution attempt (see also picture below):

We grabbed the DC after the power button of the Blaster, so that the power button also turns the Pico on and off.
We added a linear low-dropout-stabilizer (LDO) to slightly pull down the voltage. It's a 5V LM1117T-5.0 - THT TO220 (data sheet)
When reading the voltage after the LDO (without Pico attached), it shows 5V, as expected. Directly at the battery and at the internal board it still shows 6V.

Problem:  As soon as the Pico is attached, the voltage drops to 3.7V before the LDO (i.e., at the blaster's board) and to 2.4V after the LDO. At the battery itself, it is still 6V. We used fresh cells.
I am new to electronics, maybe I am misunderstanding something fundamental. But I expected that the original blaster board will still be powered with 6V and the Pico gets its necessary 5V via the LDO. Why does the voltage drop so rapidly when attaching the Pico?
How can I power both microcontrollers (with slightly different voltages) from the same battery source?



Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then please come back and [edit] your question to add more information. What is the battery voltage with the attached Pico, also about 3,7V? Did you check with fresh cells? Which specific LDO is this (please add a link to its data sheet)? Doesn't the LDO need decoupling capacitors?

We can't see what regulator that is and how you connected it if there is a mistake or not. Is there any chance you can provide the info?

I added more information in the text. "Doesn't the LDO need decoupling capacitors?" I don't know - frankly this is beyond my capabilities.

@FelixS It says it requires bypass caps right there on the front page of the data sheet you linked. However that may not be the issue. We don't know if you connected to correct pins on the switch for example.

U4 on your blaster board looks like a voltage regulator. You can probably pick some +3V3 or +5V from it.

@bobflux: Well spotted! You are right; it delivers 4.2V (which seems to be the operating voltage of the internal board). Now I just need to solder these mini pins. Even if the question is now downvoted and closed, this solved my practical problem

Be aware that power consumption rises. Watch the regulator for heating, especially in this closed case.

A closed question is commonly reopened if you remove the reasons for closure. ;-) This is not a forum.

Supposed you use the correct pins after the power button:
See figure 16 of the linked data sheet. You need to provide decoupling capacitors, at least the shown output capacitor.
If you omit them, the LDO might oscillate, taking a lot of current. Most probably the series impedance between the battery and the LDO is so high that voltage is lost.

Also for ideal operation, the cap should have a certain ESR, also described on the same page. This is such an old regulator... I can't come up with a single reason to use it.

Which regulator would you recommend for this purpose? I am new to all this ...

FelixS, are you asking @Lundin? Then please add the "at" sign for notification as I did. You might want to click on that little "Help" link.

@FelixS Why must it be a linear regular to begin with? Nothing of this "lab junk" is EMC critical. There's drop-in replacement switch regulators for old TO220 linear regulators that you can use. Though they too might require external caps.
